# spring boot - understanding configuration and monitoring of embedded jetty thread pool(s)

Tags: java, spring-boot, jetty, threadpool, monitoring

1) I can see there are 2 options that I can set in spring boot properties file, `server.jetty.acceptors` and `server.jetty.selector`. I read their [documentation](http://viswamitra.github.io/blog/2015/01/31/those-threads-in-dropwizard/), couldn't really understand these. Something about accepting and monitoring client connections. Their values by default is quite small, depends on the number of cores. Does it work for a high throughput systems? Does acceptor thread just take a new connection from a client and then passes on the actual task to some other thread which is coming from a larger thread pool? What does a selector thread do?

Where are the threads that actually serve the api calls, where the controller code is being executed? Do they lie in a threadpool by default? I can see people are explicitly setting `minThreads` and `maxThreads` for dropwizard, and there are some default values associated with them as well. Does spring boot behave the same way with default values?
Some people seem to be setting thread pool explicitly:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46961363/1331342
http://jdpgrailsdev.github.io/blog/2014/10/07/spring_boot_jetty_thread_pool.html
Which thread pool is being configured here?

2) How can I monitor the thread states in the thread pool(s) of jetty? That how many threads are busy/idle/waiting etc.
If I set the thread pool explicitly, then I can probably monitor at least this thread pool using `threadPool.getBusyThreads()`, `threadPool.getQueueSize()` etc.
But is there a way to monitor the threads if I am not setting the thread pool explicitly?

Comment: Could you find an anwser to this question?

Comment: no i could not .

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: no i did not...